# Are these two different (but equivalent) ways to write down a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have the set 
$$
A=\left\{(a,0,0,1,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-4})\in R\times\{0\}^2\times\{1\}\times\mathcal{A}^{n-4} \;  \middle|  \; \begin{matrix}s(1,c_1)\neq 1 \ \text{or} \ s(c_i,c_{i+1})\notin\{\chi_{\mathcal{A}\setminus\{0\}}(c_i),1\} \\ \text{for at least one} \ 1\leq i\leq n-5 \end{matrix}\right\}
$$

then even here there is not enough space to write this set in on line.

To use less space, would it then be the same to write

> > $A\subset R\times\{0\}^2\times\{1\}\times\mathcal{A}^{n-4}$ with
> >     $$
> > A=\left\{(a,0,0,1,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-4}) \;  \middle|  \; \begin{matrix}s(1,c_1)\neq 1 \ \text{or} \ s(c_i,c_{i+1})\notin\{\chi_{\mathcal{A}\setminus\{0\}}(c_i),1\} \\ \text{for at least one} \ 1\leq i\leq n-5 \end{matrix}\right\}
> > $$

or would this cause missunderstanding or even is a completely different set?

Comment: Are you asking if $A = \{x \in S | P(x)\}$ can be written by saying $A \subseteq S$, with $A = \{x | P(x)\}$?  Yes, this is fine. Your second formulation is rather easier to read.

Comment: In fact, if the "environment" is clear from context, you can write simply "$A: P(x).$" As an example "The unit circle is defined as $\mathbf{U}:x^2+y^2 =1."$

Comment: @WillM I haven't seen that notation before.  It's also perfectly acceptable to use words: "Let $A$ be the set of $x \in S$ such that ..."

Comment: @JairTaylor Bourbaki uses it, very clever.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In fact, I was not sure if $A=\{x\in S: P(x)\}$ is the same as to say $A\subseteq S$ and $A=\{x: P(x)\}$.

Comment: @mathfemi As long as is absolutely clear what set you mean, all should be fine. Problems arise when, for instance, the environment is $\Bbb R^2$ and then you consider a function $f$ defined on $\Bbb R$  and then define the function $(x, y) \mapsto f(x)$ and talk about the set $f(x) > 1.$

Comment: Also, try to make it clear by your choice of language that you are defining $A$ rather than writing statements about it.  If you write something like "Then define $A = \ldots$ and $A \subseteq S$" this could be seen as asserting that $A \subseteq S$ as a proposition, when you mean it as part of the definition.   "Then define $A\subseteq S$ by $A = \ldots$" is better.